# Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm looking for some feedback on my implementation of the algorithm. How can I improve it? I ran into problems when calculating the larger prime numbers > 46349 due to integer overflow, but fixed that by using `sqrt` instead of `pow`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    const int CAP = number;
    bool * prime = new bool[CAP];

    for(int i = 0; i < CAP; i++){ //sets all to true for the marking
        prime[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if(i <= sqrt(number) && prime[i] == true){
            for(int j = i*i; j < number; j++){ //if %i == 0 mark false
                if(j % i == 0){               //haven't tried another way
                    prime[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if(prime[i] == true){
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As 200_success pointed out, you have not implemented a sieve. See Wikipedia's pseudo code for the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

---

You need to check if reading in a number was actually successful:

```
if (!(std::cin >> number)) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid number provided" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

(Note that you would need `cstdlib` for `EXIT_FAILURE`.)

---

`number` is a bad name. It's an int--of course it's a number. What is it's meaning? Get rid of `CAP`, and name `number` something more meaningful like `maxNumber` (or ideally something better -- I'm having a naming mental block).

---

You should only ever use bare dynamic arrays if you are implementing a container or some other low level structure. They are non-exception safe, and you have to remember to clean up the memory. Just use a pre-allocated vector, and you can retain the same performance (or maybe even better in this relatively rare circumstance).

```
std::vector<bool> prime(CAP, true);
```

Note that `std::vector<bool>` has a specialization that uses packing to save space at the cost of a few extra cycles and some rather odd semantics (you actually get a proxy object from the vector rather than a direct reference to the element).

As Jerry Coffin noted, this task is almost certainly memory constrained rather than CPU, so the higher throughput of bit-based bools should actually provide faster performance.

Also, note that as a bonus on top of automatic memory management, you get to remove your initializing loop.

---

Though in toy programs it doesn't matter, using `namespace std;` is [considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/567864), and it's a bad habit to form. Instead, use `using std::cout;`, `using std::endl;`, etc to only import certain symbols (and do it inside of a function, not at the global level).

---

It's not technically wrong, but it's much, much more common to use a space between #include and the file:

```
#include <iostream>
```

---

`//if %i == 0 mark false` this comment says the exact same thing the code does. Either make it much more meaningful (`// mark the number non-prime if it is divisible by i`), or--better in this situation--just remove it.

---

Interactive programs should be avoided if at all possible. They cannot be chained with other commands in a scripted fashion, and they are prone to user error. Instead, when you're only accepting one or a few simple user inputs, just use arguments to the program (i.e. use `argv` to get the maximum number rather than using `std::cin`).

---

In C++, if a return value is not specified in main, it is assumed to be `EXIT_SUCCESS` (0). Because of this, I like to omit return values in main when it's not possible for the program to result in a non successful return. Seeing a `return` in main makes me immediately wonder if it can fail. (Your program actually should be able to fail, so I would keep the return, you just should also have some error checking on the input reading).

Comment: For this task, `vector<bool>` will often be faster than other containers. You lose a little CPU time to isolate one bit of storage, but in exchange you reduce the memory bandwidth by about 8:1. It's normally limited by memory bandwidth, not CPU speed, so (for this task) that typically ends up a win.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah, makes sense I suppose since basically every loop iteration is going to have to pull new data into the cache. Will update accordingly in a moment.

Answer (score 9):

The title of your post says that you want to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  However, your code also performs trial division, and has a `sqrt()` operation that is typically used as a limit when performing trial division.  You should be able to implement the Sieve without doing any division or modulo operation at all.  As for the `sqrt()` limit check, it is superfluous, as the inner loop checks that `i * i < number`.

Comment: You're right. I checked the wiki for Sieve of Eratosthenes and it states that it is often confused for trial division. Time to start over again.

Answer (score 6):

- `<math.h>` is a C header.  Use the C++ header `<cmath>`.
- If you have a dynamically-allocated array with `new`, you *must* use `delete` at some point afterwards, otherwise you'll get a memory leak:

  ```
  delete [] prime;
  ```
- When comparing something with a `bool`, you don't need to explicitly use `true` or `false`.

  For `true`:

  ```
  if (someBool) {}
  ```

  For `false`:

  ```
  if (!someBool) {}
  ```
- Do you really need `CAP`?  It's set to the same value as `number`, except it's `const`.
- You don't need `std::endl` in the loop.  This also flushes the buffer, which is slower.  Instead, use `"\n"` to produce just a newline.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea `std::endl` was that much slower. When should I use `std::endl`?

Comment: @Lanyard: You would usually use at the end of a large output, or if you need to flush the buffer immediately.  More info can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Comment: @Lanyard: My advice would be to *never* use `endl`. If you want a new-line, use `\n`. If you want to flush the stream, I think it's better to pass `std:flush` to make that intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that returns a `vector<int>` of all the primes up to the given limit.  I kept with the dynamic bool array since even a vector seemed to be 4 times slower.  There are a number of optimizations that I haven't really seen covered before:

Edit: It appears compiler optimization helps quite a bit.  with full optimization the vector is faster.  without it's slower.

```
vector<int> MakePrimes2(int upperlimit)
{
    int bound = (int) floor(sqrt(upperlimit));
    vector<bool> primes(upperlimit, true);
    vector<int> outval;    
    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;
    //Since 2 is a special case if we do it separately we can optimize the rest since 
    //they will all be odd
    for(int i = 4; i < upperlimit; i += 2)
    {
        primes[i] = false;
    }
    outval.push_back(2);
    //Since the only ones we need to look at are odd we can step by 2
    for (int i = 3; i  <= bound; i += 2)
    {
        if (primes[i]) 
        {
            //Since we are looping already we might as well start filling the 
                    //outval vector
            outval.push_back(i);
            //Since all the even multiples are already accounted for we start 
                    //at the square of the number 
            //and since it is odd skip to every other multiple
            for (int j = i*i; j < upperlimit; j += i * 2)
            {
                primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //Fill the rest of the vector starting one past the square root of the upperlimit
    for(int i = bound+1;i < upperlimit; i++)
    {
        if(primes[i])
            outval.push_back(i);
    }
    return outval;
}
```

Returning a vector like this instead of the bool array simplifies your loop to display the list of primes, and is a very minor hit on speed

Update: Did some more tests and using a loop to compare vectors made with my code and with standard code found them to be identical with my method approximately 35% faster finding all the primes up to 1,000,000,000.

Comment: Can you post your code that used a vector (perhaps a pastebin or gist)? I'm quite surprised that it was slower if your compiler's optimizations were cranked up. Was the vector sized from creation, or grown?

Comment: Same code just replaced the declaration for primes to a vector, `vector<bool> primes(upperlimit, true);`

Comment: On closer look, this has a lot of dubious code in it. It's implied that you're using `using namespace std` which is fine in implementation files, but without noting that, it's a bit odd. Also, I don't think this function is correct. Have you checked it's output with something like `MakePrimes2(1000000)`? Also, depending on undefined behavior ("on my compiler...") is questionable. Edit: just realized the bug is likely actually due to the use of undefined behavior.

Comment: I've checked the output against slower but established code and saw nothing wrong and went as high as 100,000,000.  I've even used 2 different compiler/ide's and got comparable results.

Comment: Seems the vector version is correct (once the extraneous delete[] is removed). The array based version was bugged for compilers (e.g. all of them when optimizations are enabled) that don't zero the array.

Comment: Yep found the same thing.  I added some notes about my speed tests.